# How to check if Outlook is running, using vbscript

Tags: vbscript, outlook.application

How to check if Outlook is running, using vbscript, I need this for my installation procedure to ask the user to close outlook before installing my application.

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

You could try obtaining the Outlook Application object using the [`GetObject`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdccchxa(VS.85).aspx) function. If the function call succeeds, this means that Outlook is currently running:

```
On Error Resume Next
Dim Outlook: Set Outlook = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

If Err.Number = 0 Then
  ' Outlook is running
Else
  ' Outlook is not running
  Err.Clear
End If

On Error Goto 0
```

Comment: I think you need a comma (pathname, class): GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

Comment: Maybe add an `On Error Goto 0` at the end so that any other errors in the procedure do not get suppressed.

Answer (score 4):

```
Dim Process, strObject, strProcess
Const strComputer = "." 
strProcess = "OUTLOOK.exe"
IsProcessRunning = False
strObject   = "winmgmts://" & strComputer
For Each Process in GetObject( strObject ).InstancesOf( "win32_process" )
If UCase( Process.name ) = UCase( strProcess ) Then
        MsgBox "Outlook is running"
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Beware... is my vista64 version going to be an instance of a win32_process ??

Answer (score 0):

call CheckOutlookAndSendEmail

Sub MailViaOutlook()
    Dim OutApp 
    Dim OutMail
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

```
On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = "youremailid"
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = "your Subject"
    .Body =" Thanks - .......:)"

    .Send
End With
On Error GoTo 0

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing
```

End Sub

'Below function is for open Outlook

sub OpenOutlook()

```
Dim WshShell
Set WshShell=WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "Outlook"
If Err <> 0 then
    Err.Clear
    Set ObjOL= CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
End If
```

End sub
'End Function OpenOutlook

Sub CheckOutlookAndSendEmail()

```
dim Process, strObject, strProcess
Const strComputer = "." 
strProcess = "OUTLOOK.exe"
strObject   = "winmgmts://" & strComputer
For Each Process in GetObject( strObject ).InstancesOf( "win32_process" )
    If UCase( Process.name ) = UCase( strProcess ) Then
        call MailViaOutlook ' no need to open outlook as it is already open, Hence using the exesting and send email 
        exit sub        
    end if

Next
call OpenOutlook    ' Open Outlook
call MailViaOutlook ' send email using outlook
```

end if

End Sub